# Linear Endogenous treatment effect model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, endogeneity

I am investigating the impact of MAC clauses on offer premium and i want to use Linear Endogenous treatment model address endogeneity. The MAC clause is a dummy variable with 1 if there is MAC and 0, otherwise. In the first stage regression. i estimate MAC =f(Market Cap, toehold, ROA, tech, regulated). In the second stage, i estimate Premium =f(MarketCAP, MAC, toehold, ROA, tech, MAC*MarketCAP). I would like to find if in endogenous linear regression model, it is allowed to include the interaction term (ie MAC*MarketCAP) in the premium regression.